# Definition of linear independence of a vector

Tags: linear-algebra

The definition of linear independence of a vector.

Let V be a vector space over k. The vector $v_1,v_2,...,v_n ∈ V$ are said to be linearly independent if ∃ scalar $c_1,c_2,...,c_n ∈ K$ not all zero such that $$v_1c_1 + v_2c_2 +... +v_nc_n ≠ 0$$

Is this definition correct about the linear independence of a vector?

Comment: The only combination of scalars $c_1,\cdots, c_n$ such that $c_1v_1+\cdots + c_nv_n = 0$ is $c_1 = c_2 = \cdots = c_n = 0$

Comment: The span of a set of vectors is $c_1v_1 + ... + c_nv_n$. That is, all the vectors you can possibly make with scalar multiplication and your set of vectors. A set of vectors is linearly dependent if there's a non-trivial way to make the zero vector with your set (that is, if zero is in the span of your set). The trivial way to do this is to multiply your vectors by zero, which can always be done, and we are ignoring this case. If your set is linearly dependent, then you can span one of your vectors, with the other vectors.

Comment: It looks like you might have tried to negate the definition of linear dependence. When you do that, you have to change “for all” to “there exists” and vice-versa.

Comment: Yes that's what I have tried, and I understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the correct definition is

*Let V be a vector space over k. The vector $v_1,v_2,...,v_n \in V$ are said to be linearly independent if $\color{red}{\not \exists}$ scalars $c_1,c_2,...,c_n \in  K$ not all zero such that $v_1c_1 + v_2c_2 +... +v_nc_n \color{red}{=0}$*

Comment: I understood now sir

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not. In the case you wrote they are dependent. Correct definiton is:

If from $$v_1c_1 + v_2c_2 +... +v_nc_n = 0$$ we have $c_1= c_2 = ...=c_n =0$ then they are linear independent.

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't. Consider $\hat e_1 = (0,1)$ and $2 \hat e_1 = (0,2)$ in $R^2$. They are certainly not linear independent, but there exist scalars $c_1,c_2$, such that $c_1 \hat e_1 + c_2 2\hat e_1 \neq 0$, e.g. $c_1 = c_2 = 1$. 
Try to find the right definition somewhere in the internet or in your book and ask again, if you don't understand what is wrong with yours.